JPA repository return emply list for Many to Many strategy
I have:
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
data class Employee(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Column(name = "position")
    var position: String,

    @Column(name = "name")
    var name: String,

    @Column(name = "surname")
    var surname: String,

    @Column(name = "authorized_signature")
    var authorized_signature: Boolean?,

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "signedEmployees")
    var trip: MutableSet<Trip> = mutableSetOf(),

    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_filial")
    var filial: Filial,

    //val user_id: Int? = null,
)

and
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip")
data class Trip(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Column(name = "id_country")
    var idCountry: Int,

    @Column(name = "id_hotel")
    var idHotel: Int,

    @Column(name = "days_amount")
    var daysAmount: Int,

    @Column(name = "id_client")
    var idClient: Int,

    @Column(name = "amount_of_people")
    var amountOfPeople: Int,

    @Column(name = "id_employee")
    var idEmployee: Int,

    @ManyToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "trip_employee",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "trip_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")]
    )
    var signedEmployees: MutableSet<Employee> = mutableSetOf(),

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "trips")
    var tours: Set<Tour> = mutableSetOf(),
)

When I connect trip with employee, I can see record in Many-to-many table, like here:

trip_id: 32 employee_id 3

but when I load data from an API call, my last record has empty list for signedEmployees set (see screenshots)
What might be the reason and how to fix it?
I tried to use single directional many to many.

I can't see the screenshots, did you forget to attach them?

Do you have logging enabled for jpa? It should tell you the query it is trying to execute on the DB which should help you figure out where it is going wrong
